# Is there an online national repository of marriage documents?

Tags: marriage-records, ancestry.com

I found an index on ancestry.com for my person that says it came from the U.S. and International Marriage Records, 1560-1900. The index only gives limited information from the document such as both names, marriage date, and marriage place but leaves out most other information. Why wouldn't Ancestry let me access the actual record and is there some other on-line place (preferably free) where I can find such records?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  This is a very good question -- but I have put it on hold because it is a near-duplicate of a previous question.  If you want to edit your question to ask about a specific search result from that database (to ask if there might be other places to get that information) please use the edit link under your question. If the answers here and to the previous question don't help, edit your question and let us know why not  We also encourage all new users to take the [tour] and to take a look at the [help] and [Meta] to get more information about how the site works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, you need to understand what the dataset you are looking at is, and where the data comes from.

On the search page for [U.S. and International Marriage Records, 1560-1900](http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=7836), scroll down the page and you see a section that describes the collection. It states:

> This database contains marriage record information for approximately
>   1,400,000 individuals from across all 50 United States and 32
>   different countries around the world between 1560 and 1900. These
>   records, which include information on over 500 years of marriages,
>   were extracted from family group sheets, electronic databases,
>   biographies, wills, and other sources. Compiled over thirty-four years
>   by professional genealogist Bill Yates, these marriage records are
>   unique because they were taken from a wide array of sources and stand
>   to provide a great deal of information about entire families.
>
> Source materials for these marriage records include family group
>   sheets, pedigree charts, family history articles, queries, letters,
>   Bible records, wills, and manuscript genealogies. Researching with
>   this unique database, you may be able to learn the full names of the
>   bride and groom, their birth dates and places, the year and/or month
>   they were married, and the marriage location. One of the most useful
>   features of this collection is that once you find an ancestor in this
>   database, you have the opportunity to quickly and easily obtain a
>   great deal more information about that individual by contacting Yates
>   Publishing (see next paragraph).
>
> The marriage records in this database were provided by Yates
>   Publishing. Yates Publishing has been publishing genealogical books,
>   periodicals, and quarterlies since 1972. In 1981, the founder, Bill
>   Yates, began a service to provide and collect the family history
>   information in family group sheets. Called the Family Group Sheet
>   Exchange, this service has collected over 200,000 pages of family
>   group sheets on paper and several hundred thousand more on disk. For
>   more information or to order an original Family Group Sheet on the
>   Family Group Sheet Exchange, please visit Yates Publishing.

In summary, the marriage records in this collection are not derived from a primary source, but from family group sheets.

This explains why Ancestry.com does not (cannot) display the "actual record" - they do not have the primary source.

Your intuition is good, though, to want to see the primary source material. Unfortunately, there is no international repository for marriage records. There is no point in listing here all the possible places you may find such source material, as the answer will vary tremendously depending on the date and location of the marriage. It will vary by country, state, province, county, etc. You can follow up this question with another question about locating a marriage record in a specific locality if you so desire.

Comment: Thank you much for your time and answer to my question. This is helpful for sure!